# What is the name of the shadow that appears in the scroll of the list view?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I want to change that color, becuase by default with themeData.dark() is green

Comment: Please be more specific or provide a screen shot that my help us answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by the 'shadow', you mean this effect:
[image: u mean this effect]

Then this effect is called **overscroll glow effect**, and to change it you need to change ColorScheme.secondary based on this [(docs)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html).

So it will be something like this:

```
Theme(
data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
    accentColor: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```